# Sikuli actions inside a region

Tags: java, sikuli

i am facing an issue while using sikuli through java, if there are 2 elements of same kind(or similar image) it fails to click on the correct element. so i wanted to know if it is possible to make sikuli just work inside a particular region and can some one please explain how can it be done ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes sikuli can work within a particular region.  The challenge is defining a region that only contains one of your two elements.  You define a region by x,y coordinates.  You can also increase the size of a region based on the location of a unique pattern (image) on your display.

```
while exists("foo.png"):
    hover("bar.png")
    ClickMeRegion = find("bar.png").nearby(5).right()
    ClickMeRegion.click("baz.png")
```

So in the above I look for image foo.png/bar.png/baz.png image pairs that are being displayed.  First I hover on bar.png so that visually I can see which pair the script is looking at.  Then I create a region extending 5 pixels around the center of bar.png and extend this to the right of the display.  This highlights a single baz.png image.  I can then click on the one baz.png that I am interested in.

For more info on regions see: http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html